# Test if arrays are proportional

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there a nice way to test whether two arrays are proportional in MATLAB? Something like the `isequal` function but for testing for proportionality.

Comment: What is "proportional"?

Comment: If the two arrays are a scalar multiple of each other

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Is there a way to make it work if the arrays contain zero elements. The division will give `nan` values in the `C` array in those cases

Comment: @RGWinston My approach is insensitive to division by 0. `max` and `min` ignore any `nan` elements

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, I realised the problem I was having wasn't with zero elements it was because of very small floating point values (~1e-18) in both `A` and `B`. These were behaving unpredictably and messing it up, so I had to add `A(abs(A)<1e-4) = 0; B(abs(B)<1e-4) = 0;` before the division. Now it works perfectly :)

Comment: @RGWinston Ah yes. Of course.  Make sure you **always** compare with tolerances.  Such small numbers like that will wreck havoc on your code!  Glad it works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One heuristic way to do this would be to simply divide one array by another element wise, and ensure that the largest and smallest values within this result are within some tolerance.  The degenerate case is when you have zeroes in the arrays.  In this case, using `max` and `min` will not affect the way this algorithm works because those functions ignore `nan` values.  However, if **both** `A` and `B` are zero arrays, then there are an infinite number of scalar multiples that are possible and so there isn't one answer.  We'll set this to `nan` if we encounter this.

Given `A` and `B`, something like this could work:

```
C = A./B; % Divide element-wise
tol = 1e-10; % Divide tolerance

% Check if the difference between largest and smallest values are within the
% tolerance
check = abs(max(C) - min(C)) < tol;

% If yes, get the scalar multiple
if check
    scalar = C(1);
else % If not, set to NaN
    scalar = NaN;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to compute the `'cosine'` distance between the two arrays. This will give `0` if they are proportional:

```
>> pdist2([1 3 5], [10 30 50], 'cosine')
ans =
     0

>> pdist2([1 3 5], [10 30 51], 'cosine')
ans =
     3.967230676171774e-05
```

As mentioned by @rayryeng, be sure to use a tolerance if you are dealing with real numbers.

Comment: This is great! To check I understand it, the `'cosine'` distance is 1 minus the cosine of the angle between the vectors so 0 means they are parallel (proportional with +ve coefficiant) and 2 means they are anti-parallel (proportional with -ve coefficiant)

Comment: Do these stats toolbox methods give a nice way to find the scalar multiple between the two arrays?

Comment: @RGWinston Yes, your interpretation is correct. It's 1 minus the inner product divided by sqrt of product of norms (see formula in the link). In higher dimensions it's hard to visualize that as a angle, though. As for the multiple between the two vectors: `pdist2` won't give you what, AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

```
A = rand(1,5);
B = pi*A;
C = A./B; %Divide the two
PropArray = all(abs(diff(C))<(3*eps)); % check for equality within tolerance
if PropArray
    PropConst = C(1); % they're all equal, get the constant
else
    PropConst = nan; % They're not equal, set nan
end
```